# How to keep previous and new value of data?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, trace

I’m currently working on a project where we need to archive and trace all the modified data’s.

When a modification surrender, we have to kept theses information

- Who has modified the data?
- When?
- And … that’s why I’m asking this question: **Keep the previous
  and the new value of the data**.

Quickly, I have to trace every modification for every data.

**Example** :
I have a name field why the value “Morgan”.

When I modify this value, I have to be able to say to the user that the 6th of January, by XXX, **the value changed from “Morgan” to “Robert” …**

I have to find a clean and generic method to do this because a large amount of data is concerned by this behavior.

My program is in C# (.NET 4) and we are using Sql Server 2008 R2 and NHibernate for the object mapping.

Do you any ideas, experience or solution about how to do a thing like that?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused about at what point you want to have the old vs new data available. But, this can be done within a database trigger as in the following question:

[trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181305/trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Users need to view all the previous changes on every data. I try to find different solutions. Triggers is probably the best way but I wanted to get feedback from other Dev

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate Envers its what you want :)

You must use NHibernate 3.2+ (3.2 is the current release).

Its easy like

```
enversConf.Audit<Person>();
```

You can get info [here](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers) and [here](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-envers-quick-introduction)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it ASAP !

Comment: Hum, I just look at the resource you gave me and it sounds promising !

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same situation as you. I ended up doing in this way:

Save an `ActivityEntry` in the database containing an identity column (if you have multiple objects that change), an action-indicator (could be "User changed firstname", as a int), date field, userId and most important a parameter field.

Combining the values from the parameter field and the action-indicator I'm able to make strings like "{0} changed {1}'s firstname from {2} to {3}" where my parameter values could be "John;Joe".

I know it feels kinda wrong saving these totally loosely typed values in the database, but I believe it's the only way around, without having a copy of each table.

Comment: Thank for your response. And each new ActivityEntry is triggered by the database or you implemented another solution to create the database entry ?

Comment: In my solution (which wasn't perfect) I simply had a method (taking `params` of `string` parameter and the action-indicator) that I called everytime the user did something. I think it's possible to automate this if you're able to figure out the exact action that the user made.