# Updating other rows in a table from another row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `Day` entity that is a table of days. The `C#` code for that is as follows:

```
namespace Utilities.Models
{
    public class Day
    {
        public int DayID { get; set; }
        public int WeekID { get; set; }
        public int DayNo { get; set; }
        public string DayofWeek { get; set; }
        public int Meter1 { get; set; }
        public int Meter1Dailyusage {get; set; }
        //etc
    }
}
```

How do I update data from one day after another is entered?

For example, say it is Monday (`DayNo = 1` and `DayofWeek = "Monday"`) and you input the data for the meters, etc.

How do I make it so that when the user inputs for Tuesday (`DayNo = 2` and `DayofWeek = "Tuesday"`), I can use data from the meter reading from Tuesday to update Monday's `Meter1DailyUsage` row as `Meter1DailyUsage = Tuesday's meter reading - Monday's meter reading`?

Comment: What is your functional requirement? This could make what you wish to achieve easier to understand, and perhaps is it going to allow for other suggestions to come up.

Comment: As long as you're always updating the previous record id, you may want a Trigger on this table. Here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181305/trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated

Comment: My functional requirement? The meters are water meters and I want to have daily usages of water from each meter.