# How to refer to an element (a value in the most recent row) of a table that initiated a trigger in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For example:
TableA: CustomerID, CustomerName
TableB: CustomerID, CustomerOrder

```
Create Trigger ON
TableA
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT

AS
DECLARE @CustomerOrder as nvharchar(max)
Set @CustomerOrder = 'New Order'
Insert INTO TableB VALUES CustomerID(the ID that was just inserted into TableA),
@CustomerOrder
```

Comment: have a look at second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181305/trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated - it covers what your looking for, which is using the updated and inserted psuedo-tables to get the values that have changed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INSERTED table is a special table which keeps only the rows which are inserted

Insert INTO TableB (INSERTED.ID, @CustomerOrder)

More Info -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx