# Trigger for update table after update records in another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers

I need a trigger for update field on Table_2 when over any fields are Updated on table_1. I created one but when I update one record in table_1 on Table_2 it’s updating all fields.

Sample SQL:-

```
 Create trigger trigger-1  ON Table_1 After Update  
 As 
 begin  
     SET NOCOUNT ON;   
     Insert into table_2 (Col1,col2,col3,..etc) Select (ins.column names) 
     from  table_1
```

Suppose table_1 has many fields but still I need Updated fields. How to get only updated fields from table_1 to table_2 by using trigger?

Comment: are you implementing some audit trail kind of thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found perfect answer.

In the case of an `UPDATE`, the

> Deleted table will contain the old values, while the Inserted table
>   contains the new values after Update.

Based on requirement, if we want to all fields in trigger we need to mention all fields in the table and write something like:

**For records after UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ProdUpdate
ON dbo.Production 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
Begin

INSERT INTO dbo.Attribiute (ID, attributeValue, attributetype)

SELECT i.ID, i.prodrecord, i.prodvalue
FROM Production i
INNER JOIN INSERTED d ON i.ID = d.ID
```

**For Records before UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ProdUpdate
ON dbo.Production 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
Begin

INSERT INTO dbo.Attribiute (ID, attributeValue, attributetype)

SELECT i.ID, i.prodrecord, i.prodvalue
FROM Attribiute i
INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.ID = d.ID
```

We can join the Inserted and Deleted in to some History tables for audit by grabbing the Identical field (which is the same in both cases). The old value from the Deleted table, the new value from the Inserted table, and you store everything in the separate Table

For better understanding check this link [Trigger insert old values- values that was updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181305/trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You can use the `inserted` table. It contains all the column of the base table

```
INSERT INTO table_2 ( col1, col2, col3, . . .)
SELECT  i.cola, i.colb, i.colc, . . .
FROM    inserted i
```

if you need to know which columns are updated, use `UPDATE( column name )`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql

Comment: this should work. if not, please post your exact trigger