# Trigger insert old values only when changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger to do some basic logging for each field that changes in SQL Server 2019.

[Trigger insert old values- values that was updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181305/trigger-insert-old-values-values-that-was-updated)

The difference between this question and the other one is that I want to log every field that changed as a new row within my log table.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is which column has been updated when and from which value to which value.

My current table structure is this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE notizen_aktionen (
    notiz_aktion_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    notiz_id int NOT NULL,
    aktion_id int NOT NULL,
    empfaenger_id int NOT NULL,
    anlage_user_id int NOT NULL,
    beschreibung text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    status_id int NOT NULL,
    email_gesendet tinyint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE history_notizen_aktionen (
    history_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    notiz_aktion_id int NOT NULL,
    field_name varchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    old_value text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    new_value text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] datetime IDENTITY(1,1) DEFAULT getdate() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__history___2B82835CF2EB6029 PRIMARY KEY (notiz_aktion_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK__history_n__notiz__68D28DBC FOREIGN KEY (notiz_aktion_id) REFERENCES messeportal.dbo.notizen_aktionen(notiz_aktion_id)
);
```

The main reason why I am not using `temporal tables` as suggested is because I want to show all changes based on field in order for my user within my app.

For example:

```
2023-10-07 - Status changed from 10 to 20
2023-10-07 - Status changed from 0 to 10
```

Comment: It's all there in the answers? SELECT i.ID, d.Name, i.Name
      FROM Inserted i
      INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID . just add a WHERE i.SomeField <> d.SomeField

Comment: You're using SQL Server 2019; why not use a temporal table?

Comment: @siggemannenyes. But how do I provide both values indivdually to the procedure call?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a trigger is in SQL Server. When you update a table, sql server does it's thing and changes the values. But if you have triggers, it also "materializes" two tables for updates and one for insert/delete, called inserted / deleted. These pseudo-tables contains the old and new data that the actual UPDATE works with. So, inside a trigger, you don't call procedures, you just write what you want to do by accessing the tables called inserted / deleted and perform your logging or whatever. It's a very simplified explanation, you should read how triggers work

Comment: Please do not link to other questions; include everything needed in your question.

Comment: your trigger code "becomes" the procedure pretty much, and the data you need to work with will be in the inserted / deleted tables, a bit like this firebird thing, but they call them old/new. Note that sql server works on all the rows at the same time, unlike oracle and postgres, so you shouldn't assume inserted / deleted contains one row only (a mistake a lot of people do when switching between database providers)

Comment: So there is now way of using the procedure there? The main point of the procedure is to now write the same insert statement a couple hundred times when all that changes is just a field identifier and the old and new values provided to the procedure

Comment: What I basically want to track in my history table is which column has been updated when and from what to what.

Comment: Oh, now i got it, you want each *field* change to be logged as separate row? Well, yeah, it could be done with some dynamic sql too, no problem.

Comment: or just manually write out every field change as a union all

Comment: something like: insert into loggingTable (fieldName, ID, oldValue, NewValue) select 'a', i.id, o.a, i.a from inserted i inner join deleted d on d.id = i.id where i.a <> d.a union all select 'b', i.id, o.b, i.b from inserted i inner join deleted d on d.id = i.id where i.b <> d.b union all ...

Comment: Does this also works when none of the specified fields have changed? Or will it create an empty record instead? Lets say I don't want to track the field description and this field is the only one that has been changed.

Comment: I would suggest you think about actually doing this as a separate row for each change. Consider how horrific it would be to look at a row at a specific point in time. You would have to query every column in the table against your log table. I would take a hard look at temporal tables. With the exception of every single change in a new row it does everything else you are looking for. The upside is that it requires very little effort to implement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You can do this without dynamic SQL. But please show your table definition, and how you want the history table to look. I second using Temporal Tables, which does all this very well already.

Comment: I've updated my question with my table structure and what I want to achieve specifially. The solution from @siggemannen seems to be working for me. But I'll need to test more cases to be completely sure.

Comment: @MarvinKlein, there's no such thing as empty records. If no WHERE conditions hit, nothing will be inserted into your log table

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to full-join `inserted` and `deleted` by PK, then unpivot the columns into separate rows, comparing each old and new value.

On newer versions of SQL Server you can use `IS DISTINCT FROM`. Otherwise use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT v.new_value EXCEPT SELECT v.old_value)`

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tr_History ON dbo.notizen_aktionen
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  RETURN;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT history_notizen_aktionen
  (notiz_aktion_id, field_name, old_value, new_value, [timestamp])
SELECT
  ISNULL(i.notiz_aktion_id, d.notiz_aktion_id),
  v.field_name,
  v.old_value,
  v.new_value,
  SYSDATETIME()
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.notiz_aktion_id = i.notiz_aktion_id
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('notiz_id', CAST(i.notiz_id AS sql_variant), CAST(d.notiz_id AS sql_variant)),
    ('aktion_id', i.aktion_id, d.aktion_id),
    ('empfaenger_id', i.empfaenger_id, d.empfaenger_id),
    ('anlage_user_id', i.anlage_user_id, d.anlage_user_id),
    ('beschreibung', i.beschreibung, d.beschreibung),
    ('status_id', i.status_id, d.status_id),
    ('email_gesendet', i.email_gesendet, d.email_gesendet)
) v(field_name, new_value, old_value)
WHERE v.new_value IS DISTINCT FROM v.old_value;
```

Note that the `text` type is deprecated, and you should use `varchar(max)` instead, or in this case `sql_variant`.

---

Having said that, I still recommend you use Change Data Capture, which does most of this for you, and then just unpivot the results on querying it.